# Get All child element names from expandable listview in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-adapter

I am new to android.I have a Expandable Listview having childs and I m unable to get all child names. This is my adapter.And I want to get all child names present in that group when that group is selected.
Please help me..

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    private ArrayList<Boolean> _isCheckedHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<Boolean>> _listIsCheckedChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, ArrayList<Boolean> isCheckedHeader, 
            HashMap<String, List<Boolean>> listIsCheckedChild) 
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this._isCheckedHeader = isCheckedHeader;
        this._listIsCheckedChild = listIsCheckedChild;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        final CheckBox chkChild=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxchild);

        //HEREE !!!! Do this to update with a right status check...
        chkChild.setChecked(_listIsCheckedChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition));

        final int iGroupPos = groupPosition;
        final int iChildPos = childPosition;

        chkChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(chkChild.isChecked()) //the child was enable (checked), so the other of same header have to are non-checked
                {
                    //unChecking all SubItem(Childs) of this Header less this chkChild
                    int iSizeChilds = getChildrenCount(iGroupPos); //get the size of children of header
                    Log.e("iSizeChilds", String.valueOf(iSizeChilds));
                    for(int i = 0; i<iSizeChilds; i++) //for each child 
                    {
                        //disable all children
                        _listIsCheckedChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(iGroupPos)).set(i, false);
                    }


                    //And enable that i want
                    _listIsCheckedChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(iGroupPos)).set(iChildPos, true);

                    //Update the Childs Views... 
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Toast.makeText(_context, "Child "+iChildPos+" \r\nof Header "+iGroupPos+" was enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else //the child was disable (non-checked)
                {
                    _listIsCheckedChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(iGroupPos)).set(iChildPos, false);

                    Toast.makeText(_context, "Child "+iChildPos+" \r\nof Header "+iGroupPos+" was disable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        convertView.setSelected(false);
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        final CheckBox chkParent=(CheckBox)convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxparent);

        //HEREE !!!! Do this to update with a right status check...
        chkParent.setChecked(_isCheckedHeader.get(groupPosition));

        final int iPos = groupPosition;

        //Don't use this (setOnCheckedChangeListener)...
        chkParent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Don't use this...
            }
        });

        chkParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (chkParent.isChecked()) //OnClick enable it,we have to update the _isCheckedHeader
                {
                    //READ: the main code first, and after the notifications(toast, log)...
                    _isCheckedHeader.set(iPos, true);

                    //Checking all SubItem(Childs) of this
                    int iSizeChilds = getChildrenCount(iPos);
                    Log.e("iSizeChilds", String.valueOf(iSizeChilds));
                    for(int i = 0; i<iSizeChilds; i++)
                    {
                        _listIsCheckedChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(iPos)).set(i, true);
                        Log.i("Child " + i, "was setted to " + _listIsCheckedChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(iPos)).get(i));


                        ArrayList<String> allChilds = new ArrayList<String>();





                    }

                    Toast.makeText(_context, "Header "+iPos+ " was enabled(checked)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Header", iPos + "was enabled(checked)"); //i recommend that use Log to see a developping info...






                }
                else
                {
                    _isCheckedHeader.set(iPos, false);

                    //NON-Checking all SubItem(Childs) of this
                    int iSizeChilds = getChildrenCount(iPos);
                    for(int i = 0; i<iSizeChilds; i++)
                    {
                        _listIsCheckedChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(iPos)).set(i, false);
                        Log.i("Child "+i, "was setted to "+_listIsCheckedChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(iPos)).get(i));
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(_context, "Header "+iPos+ " was disable(non-checked)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Header", iPos+ "was disable(non-checked)");
                }

                //Update the Childs Views... 
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly give a look at the bellow link, you should have some link between your parent and child.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: But how to get all child values ?? on Group expand

Comment: in your:

   @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
       return the Child. for the respected group    }

the rest is done by the array adaptor, it will provide the child for the respected group